# How to make clicking some elements an exception for useClickAway hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dom-events

I have an Overlay which is opened by clicking an icon button. In that Overlay, I'm using the `useClickAway` hook exported by the `react-use` library -

```
useClickAway(overlayRef, hideOverlay);
```

Basically, whenever a user clicks anywhere outside the overlay dom node, it hides this overlay.

But with this, I'm facing one issue when a user clicks on that `icon button` (which opens this overlay), this overlay first closes and then re-opens, which causes the flickering of the overlay.

How can I make clicking on this `icon button` an exception for this `useClickAway` hook?

I have tried adding `event.stopPropagation` to click event handler on `icon button` but it didn't work.

Codesandbox Link for same - https://codesandbox.io/s/useclickaway-hook-krd6y6

Comment: Can you create a running https://codesandbox.io/ to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @LinDu I have added codesandbox link in the problem statement

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to prevent the overlay from immediately closing and reopening when the icon button is clicked, while still allowing it to close when clicking outside the overlay. Since the `useClickAway` hook triggers the `hideOverlay` function when clicking outside the overlay, you'll need a mechanism to temporarily disable this behavior when the icon button is clicked.

One way to achieve this is by using a flag to determine whether the overlay should be closed or not based on the last click event target. Here's an example of how you could modify your code to achieve this:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { useClickAway } from 'react-use';

const Overlay = () => {
  const overlayRef = useRef(null);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [shouldClose, setShouldClose] = useState(true); // Add a flag

  const toggleOverlay = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  const hideOverlay = () => {
    if (shouldClose) {
      setIsOpen(false);
    } else {
      setShouldClose(true);
    }
  };

  useClickAway(overlayRef, hideOverlay);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={toggleOverlay}>Toggle Overlay</button>
      {isOpen && (
        <div ref={overlayRef}>
          {/* Overlay content */}
          <button
            onClick={(e) => {
              setShouldClose(false); // Prevent closing
              e.stopPropagation();
            }}
          >
            Icon Button
          </button>
          {/* Other overlay content */}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Overlay;
```

In this example, the `shouldClose` flag is used to determine whether the overlay should be closed when the `useClickAway` hook triggers the `hideOverlay` function. When the icon button is clicked, the `shouldClose` flag is temporarily set to `false`, preventing the overlay from closing immediately. The `e.stopPropagation()` call prevents the event from propagating and affecting the overlay's closing behavior.

Remember that the above example assumes a basic overlay structure. You might need to adapt it to fit your specific code and styling.

Comment: The example that I've added in the above code sandbox is super simplified. In my actual code, this button's code and the overlay's code are in separate files. In short, it won't be possible to maintain a state variable that can be shored across their code like above.

Answer (score 0):

The `onClickAway` hook doesn't support excluding HTML elements, its callback will be called if the element you click is not the descendant element of the overlay element. See [`!el.contains(event.target)`](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/325f5bd69904346788ea981ec18bfc7397c611df/src/useClickAway.ts#L18).

You have to exclude the HTML elements by yourself. You can get the `mousedown` `event` object in the handler. See [`onClickAway: (event: E) => void`](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/325f5bd69904346788ea981ec18bfc7397c611df/src/useClickAway.ts#L8C35-L8C35)

If the `event.target` is the button element, don't close the overlay.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import useClickAway from "react-use/lib/useClickAway";

export default function App() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const overlayRef = useRef<null | HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const buttonRef = useRef<HTMLButtonElement | null>(null);

  useClickAway(overlayRef, (event) => {
    if(event?.target === buttonRef.current) return;
    setIsOpen(false);
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        ref={buttonRef}
        onClick={() => {
          setIsOpen(true);
        }}
      >
        Open Overlay
      </button>
      {isOpen ? (
        <div ref={overlayRef} id="overlay">
          Overlay
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/useclickaway-hook-forked-wgp2yq?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

Have fixed it by adding following event listener to button -

```
onMouseDown={(event) => {
   event.stopPropagation();
}}
```